# PHP: How to catch Fatal error: Cannot declare class [myclassname], because the name is already in use

Tags: php, exception

I am implementing a plugin controller CLASS for client created custom plugins.
Since the names of the classes of each plugin could very well end up clashing with other plugins already installed, I want to make sure we don't get fatal errors when a new plugin comes in.
I want to report to the user that the new plugin is clashing with an already installed one.

So basically atm I testing with 2 files both containing exactly the same code and am getting:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class [myclassname], because the name is already in use
```

I have tried catching this with no success using:

```
try {
    include_once $file; 
} catch (ClosedGeneratorException|DOMException|ErrorException|IntlException|LogicException|BadFunctionCallException|BadMethodCallException|DomainException|InvalidArgumentException|LengthException|OutOfRangeException|PharException|ReflectionException|RuntimeException|OutOfBoundsException|OverflowException|PDOException|RangeException|UnderflowException|UnexpectedValueException|SodiumException $ex) {
    echo "Unable to load file.";
}
```

All these I got from Lists of Throwable and Exception tree as of 7.2.0 in https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

The manual specifies that:

> The thrown object must be an instance of the Exception class or a
> subclass of Exception. Trying to throw an object that is not will
> result in a PHP Fatal Error.

Is it possible that this is not an object of instance/suclass of the Exception class?
What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ - that no one anywhere _throws_ any exception here in the first place. You are trying to catch something, that doesn’t exist.

Comment: How can one know that a Fatal Error is not 'Catch'able?

Comment: Anything catchable will have an error message along the lines of "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error ...*". Note the uppercase E in Error - it's referring specifically to the Error class, which is a subtype of `Throwable`

Comment: is your comment based on experience or did you read this somewhere? links?

Comment: A bit of both - the Throwable hierarchy is explained in the docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php), but I don't know of any good documentation about which internal errors are under the new hierarchy and which aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you're not missing anything. Declaring a duplicate class name can't be caught in any version of PHP (including 8.0.0 as far as the alpha releases). See https://3v4l.org/2TLA3

For some additional background, PHP does sometimes move errors like these underneath the `Throwable` hierarchy, so that they can be detected at runtime. PHP 7 added support for catching an attempt to instantiate a missing class, and 7.3 added support for catching an attempt to *extend* a missing class. See https://3v4l.org/BDnm9 for a brief demo of those.

Comment: Can't be caught... Can it be circumvented? Can it be avoided? I cannot have the fatal error popping up. Worst comes to worst I will have to parse the file...

Comment: Encourage the people writing the plugins to at least put them in a custom namespace. If you're running user-supplied code then this is always a risk - you've only really got convention (or a review process) to prevent it.

Comment: Not used namespaces before so I have to ask... What if they use the same namespace as the name of their class? will there be a namespace clash then? and back to square one?

Comment: Namespaces definitely sound like a good solution. You'll only get a clash if the full namespace + class name overlaps with another. They're really designed to fix this kind of problem (as well as helping with readability). I'd suggest reading up on them and working out how they could fit into your workflow

Comment: That's what I meant. If I enforce the use of namespaces, developers will probably name them the same as their class. This would create the same problem. I would have to ask them to create namespaces which are never the same name as their class name. This way randomness comes into play and the chances of 2 namespace/classname being equal diminishes. It could be a solution.

Comment: Developers should be using a namespace that's unique to them - this could be their name, username, whatever. A classname doesn't make much sense as a namespace - if I personally write two plugins, they should be in the same namespace

Answer (score 0):

In the end, to avoid this fatal error I decide to parse the files for the first available class declaration using tokens as follows:

```
public function getClassInFile($filenpath) {
    $src = $this->uncommentFile($filenpath);
    $class ='';
    if (preg_match('/class[\s\n]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[\s\na-zA-Z0-9_]+\{/', $src, $matches)) {
        $class = $matches[1];
    }
    return $class;
}

public function uncommentFile($filenpath) {
    $fileStr = file_get_contents($filenpath);
    $newStr  = '';

    $commentTokens = array(T_COMMENT);

    if (defined('T_DOC_COMMENT'))
    $commentTokens[] = T_DOC_COMMENT; // PHP 5
    if (defined('T_ML_COMMENT'))
    $commentTokens[] = T_ML_COMMENT;  // PHP 4

    $tokens = token_get_all($fileStr);

    foreach ($tokens as $token) {    
        if (is_array($token)) {
            if (in_array($token[0], $commentTokens))
            continue;

            $token = $token[1];
        }

        $newStr .= $token;
    }

    return $newStr; 
}
```

In this way, I can check whether the class I am expecting to find is in there, or if the class in there already exists, thus avoiding to include_once altogether in these cases.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved such problems the same way we do that in C for header files:

`if (!class_exists("My_View_Helper_Bootstrapmenu")):
 ... define class
endif;`

Opinions about style and stupidity of code or quality of certain frameworks are not welcome here according to stackoverflow rules so I just post this as-is.